# Eclipse says "Constructor is undefined"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a custom ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class DrawerArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

int disabledItemPosition;

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(disabledItemPosition ==position){
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.isEnabled(position);
    }
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects, int disabledItemPosition) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.disabledItemPosition = disabledItemPosition;
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

But when I try to construct it with:

```
new DrawerArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles, 9)
```

Eclipse complains that "The constructor DrawerArrayAdapter(MainActivity, int, String[], int) is undefined"

Comment: And Eclipse or rather Java is right. Where do you have a constructor like that?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? It's pretty clear.

Comment: Probably because it is undefined. You have a constructor that takes an array, and one that takes a list and an int, but not one that takes an array and an int.

Comment: My fault, seems I should get a rest, the correct constructor is:`public DrawerArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects, int disabledItemPosition) {
  super(context, resource, objects);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  this.disabledItemPosition = disabledItemPosition;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String arrays can't cast to List and maybe I miss the 4 params constructor with String (or T ) array but I think that that is the problem.